# How to get value from select option and at the same time use @onchange to do a function. (blazor)

Tags: bind

```
<select @bind="Project.Supplier" @onchange="LoadProjectTypes">
   <option value="0">Select Supplier</option>

   @foreach (var supplier in ProjectSuppliers)
    {
        <option>@supplier.SupplierName</option>
    }
</select>

@code{
private ProjectModel Project;
private List<ProjectSuppliersModel> ProjectSuppliers;

public void CreateProject()
{
    //a function to insert the current project in the database
}

protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    ProjectSuppliers = _db.GetProjectSuppliers();
}
```

> I want to get the selected Project.Supplier from select-option and then sent it to the data base.
> at the same time I want to use LoadProjectTypes function. but there is an error in the select element like this: "The attribute 'onchange' is used two or more times for this element".
> How can I solve it. Am I missing something?
> to be more clear: the function LoadProjectTypes affect another select element to show project types which is related just to the selected project supplier as its options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the hood, @bind uses @onchange to set your variable, so you can't use both.

I think you don't need 2-way binding for dropdowns usually, so I recommend the "Unbound" example in the following.  But if you REALLY want to do 2-way binding, then you can catch the value change in a custom `get; set;` for the variable instead of trying to catch the actual event.

```
@page "/onchange"

<select @onchange="HandleOnChangeUnbound">
    <option disabled selected>Select an option</option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
</select>
<br />
@if (UnboundSelected is not null)
{
    <div>@UnboundSelected</div>
}
<select @bind="BoundSelected">
    <option disabled selected>Select an option</option>
    <option>Option A</option>
    <option>Option B</option>
    <option>Option C</option>
</select>
@if (DisplayBound is not null)
{
    <div>@DisplayBound</div>
}



@code {
    string UnboundSelected { get; set; }
    string DisplayBound { get; set; }
    private string _boundSelected;
    public string BoundSelected
    {
        get
        {
            return _boundSelected;
        }
        set
        {
            _boundSelected = value;
            HandleOnChangeBound(value);
        }
    }
    void HandleOnChangeUnbound(ChangeEventArgs args)
    {
        UnboundSelected = args.Value.ToString();
        // Do DB stuff.
    }
    void HandleOnChangeBound(string value)
    {
        DisplayBound = value;
        // Do DB stuff
    }
}
```